# Python Heatmap with calculated fields

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, heatmap

Looking to create a heatmap from a dataframe. Index is each event of car crashes. Columns are Year, Month (1 - 12, Day of the Week (1- 7), Hour of Day (0 - 23), Fatal (1) non Fatal (2), etc.

I trying to create a heatmap with the x axis being Hour of Day, and y axis being Day of the Week. Looking to create a calculated field for each "cell", corresponding to the fatality rate of each hour and day.

````
Sunday
Saturday
Friday
Thursday
Wednesday
Tuesday
Monday

          0  1 2 3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 etc```
````

```
dbh = df[df.Fatal == 1].groupby('Hour').Fatal.count()
sbh = df[df.Fatal == 2].groupby('Hour').Fatal.count()
final_dbh = (dbh /(sbh+ dbh)* 100)

Hour
0.0     3.429764
1.0     3.696422
2.0     3.559404
3.0     4.093886
4.0     3.464674
5.0     3.276747
6.0     1.827378
7.0     1.021872
8.0     0.928400
9.0     1.201049
10.0    1.234164
11.0    1.477833
12.0    1.437418
13.0    1.705571
14.0    1.595436
15.0    1.219512
16.0    1.256826
17.0    1.514321
18.0    1.375315
19.0    1.384932
20.0    2.331501
21.0    2.066446
22.0    1.997928
23.0    3.506366
Name: Fatal, dtype: float64

dbd = df[df.Fatal == 1].groupby('Weekday').Fatal.count()
sbd = df[df.Fatal == 2].groupby('Weekday').Fatal.count()
final_dbd = (dbd /(sbd + dbd)* 100)

Weekday
7    2.070770
4    1.694125
6    1.602799
5    1.579378
3    1.524816
1    1.473684
2    1.282576
Name: Fatal, dtype: float64
```

```
db = df[df['Fatal'] == 1]
df_test = db.groupby(["Month" , "Weekday"]).Fatal.count()
```

```
Month  Weekday
1.0    1           34
       2           48
       3           43
       4           75
       5           36
```

I think I've sorted out for to get the numbers I need, but how to assign them to the heatmap I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

First, use your data to make a 2-D matrix with rows representing the days (sunday, ...) and the columns representing the numbers (0  1 2 3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18).

Once you have this 2-D matrix use the below code to plot the heatmap

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create a 10x10 random matrix
data = np.random.random((10, 10))   # REPLACE WITH YOUR DATA
print(data.shape)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data)

# show image
plt.show()
```